# how can I avoid validation of the caller id when I make a call to Twilio via trunk?

Tags: verify, trunk, incoming-call, caller-id

When I redirect a call to Twilio via trunk I want to know the callerId of the first number and Twilio tells me that I need to verify the number first.

I call a phone number (phone1 to phone2) and the second one redirects the call to Twilio via trunk. I want to be able to identify phone1 without verifying it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I redirect a call via trunk I get the error "32204 - SIP: 'From' phone number not verified" and I want to avoid the verification